# How much we should care about using the String.intern().

Tags: java, performance

I was studying about the String.intern() and its uses.
But I am not able to figure out that at what level it will efficent.
and How it is not going to complicat the code/logics.

Comment: @AnubianNoob : thnks :)

Comment: Glad I could help! In the future, try running a google search before asking here, it'll save you a lot of time and trouble :)